# Mysql Union All & order by

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables

table member

```
id   |   type
1    |    A
2    |    B
3    |    A
```

table commission A

```
id   |  member_id   |     date     |   amount   |
1    |     1        |  2017-06-06  |   30.00    |
2    |     2        |  2017-06-18  |   20.00    |
3    |     1        |  2017-06-21  |   10.00    |
4    |     3        |  2017-06-23  |   30.00    |
5    |     3        |  2017-06-27  |   30.00    |
```

table commission B

```
id   |  member_id   |     date     |   amount   |
1    |     2        |  2017-06-05  |   30.00    |
2    |     2        |  2017-06-13  |   30.00    |
3    |     1        |  2017-06-22  |   30.00    |
4    |     3        |  2017-06-22  |   30.00    |
5    |     1        |  2017-06-23  |   30.00    |
```

i want result to show only member type A, and order by date

```
id  |     date       |   member id   |    from
1   |   2017-06-06   |      1        |   table A
3   |   2017-06-21   |      1        |   table A
3   |   2017-06-22   |      1        |   table B
4   |   2017-06-22   |      3        |   table B
5   |   2017-06-23   |      1        |   table B
```

and total amount = 130

I tried this:

```
select member_id, date, amount 
from commission A 
union all 
select member_id, date, amount 
from commission B 
order by date asc
```

But I couldn't select only members of type A: my query shows all members' results.

How should I do it?

Comment: What query have you tried?

Comment: select member_id, date, amount from commission A union all select member_id, date, amount from commission B order by date asc

Comment: i couldn't select member type A only selected, my query show all member result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the `members` table in order to filter on the type:

```
select      c.*
from        member m
inner join (
            select id, member_id, `date`, amount, 'table A' `from`
            from   commissionA
            union all
            select id, member_id, `date`, amount, 'table B' `from`
            from   commissionB
           ) c
        on  m.id = c.member_id
where       m.type = 'A'
order by    c.`date` asc
```

NB: I would avoid names like `date` and `from`, since they have special meanings.

To get the total in an additional row, group by all the fields (except amount), and add the `with rollup` clause. Finally, filter out any subtotals that are generated:

```
select *
from   (
    select      c.id, c.member_id, c.`date`, sum(c.amount) amount, c.`from`
    from        member m
    inner join (
                select id, member_id, `date`, amount, 'table A' `from`
                from   commissionA
                union all
                select id, member_id, `date`, amount, 'table B' `from`
                from   commissionB
               ) c
            on  m.id = c.member_id
    where       m.type = 'A'
    group by    c.id, c.member_id, c.`date`, c.`from` with rollup) base
where       id is null or `from` is not null;
order by    `date` asc
```

Comment: how about the total amount? where should i add SUM()?

Comment: I added a section about that in my answer.